# uniformly continuous and bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis

When I learn uniformly continuous function, I used to view uniformly continuous function as a function with bounded derivative.

Most of time up to now it seems right. But can we prove or disprove that the uniformly continuous functions are functions with bounded derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is quite false. The absolute value function $|x|$ is uniformly continuous, but isn't differentiable (the derivative, however, does exist almost everywhere and is bounded). This can be easily extended to give a uniformly Lipschitz function whose derivative fails to exist at a given finite set.

For a better counterexample, note that the function $x^{1/3}$ is uniformly continuous, but its derivative doesn't exist at $0$, and is unbounded in every neighborhood of zero.

For an even more spectacular example, the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is uniformly continuous on $[-1,1]$, but is differentiable nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a continuous function need not have a derivative at all.

But assuming $f$ is differentiable and has bounded derivative everywhere, we can say $$|f'(x)|<M$$ so by the Mean Value Theorem $$\left|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right|=|f'(c)|<M\implies |f(b)-f(a)|<M|b-a|$$ Therefore given $\epsilon >0$, we take $\delta=\epsilon/M$ to get $$|f(b)-f(a)|<M{\epsilon\over M}=\epsilon$$ and the function is uniformly continuous.